# Installing Oracle Express Database 18c (XE) On Oracle Cloud Free Tier Fails With ORA-00821: Specified value of sga_target | minimum requirements

Tags: oracle

### **Scenario**

1. Tried to install **Oracle Express Database 18c (XE)** on Oracle Cloud **Free Tier** ( Centos 7 machine ).
2. Followed steps suggested in : **[Oracle installation doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/xeinl/procedure-installing-oracle-database-xe.html)**
3. As Oracle Cloud Free Tier machine is **limited to 1000MB** memory, **installation fails with 2 different major issues** :
4. Encountered **2 major issues** :

   - **Issue 1** : [SEVERE] Oracle Database 18c Express Edition requires a minimum of 1GB of physical memory (RAM).  This system has **971 MB of RAM and does not meet minimum requirements.**"
   - **Issue 2** : [WARNING] **ORA-00821**: Specified value of s**ga_target 296M is too small**, needs to be at least 400M
     **ORA-01078**: failure in processing system parameters

Answer (score 2):

### **How to Install Oracle Database 18c Express Edition on Oracle Cloud Free Tier (for life) | Centos 7**

---

**Credits** : 
[1](http://mobile.oaktable.net/content/how-install-oracle-xe-18c-oracle-cloud-free-tier)
[2](https://gamblisfx.com/how-to-install-oracle-database-18c-xe-on-centos-7-6/)

**STEP 1 - Download Oracle Required Software**

- oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
- oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm

```
1. mkdir Downloads
2. cd /home/opc/Downloads
3. curl -L -O https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/otn_software/db-express/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
3. curl -L -O https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/latest/x86_64/getPackage/oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
4. sudo yum localinstall oracle-database-preinstall-18c-1.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm (Pre-Requistis only)
```

---

**STEP 2 - Change RPM To Avoid Issue 1** :

( Issue 1 : This system has 971 MB of RAM and does not meet minimum requirements )

- Install & run **rpmrebuild** (if you don't have it already)

```
1. sudo yum install rpmrebuild
2. cd /home/opc
3. rpmrebuild -e -p /home/opc/oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
   ( this might take few mins )
```

- Once rpmrebuild **is opened** :

```
1. Scroll down ( to bottom ) -> search for this line : [ $PhyMem -lt 1024 ]
2. Change to : [ $PhyMem -lt 102 ]
3. Press Esc -> type : wq!
4. Wait for RPM to be re-build ( it's auto and take few mins ).
```

- Do the rpmrebuild **modification** :

```
1. Scroll down ( to bottom ) -> search for this line : [ $PhyMem -lt 1024 ]
2. Change to : [ $PhyMem -lt 102 ]
3. Press Esc -> type : wq!
4. Wait for RPM to be re-build ( it's auto and take few mins ).
```

- **Install Database** from new RPM  :

```
1. cd /home/opc/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/
2. sudo yum localinstall oracle-database-xe-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
```

---

**STEP 3 - Change Config File** Before Database Configuration To Avoid Issue 2 :

( Issue 2 : sga_target 296M is too small )

- Once step 2 completed - Edit File : /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c

```
1. sudo -s
2. cp /etc/sysconfig/oracle-xe-18c.conf /etc/sysconfig/oracle-xe-18c.orig
3. vi /etc/sysconfig/oracle-xe-18c.conf 
4. search for "sga_target=" (/sga_target= in vi)
5. change from : MEMORY_CONSTRUCT="-initParams sga_target=${sga}M,pga_aggregate_target=${pga}M"
          To   : MEMORY_CONSTRUCT="-initParams sga_target=500M,pga_aggregate_target=${pga}M"
6. Save file.
```

---

**STEP 4 - Run Database Configuration** :

( This may take up to 30 mins )

```
1. /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure
```

Comment: I think that the change in step 3 must be made in /etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c, and not in /etc/sysconfig/oracle-xe-18c.conf .